# JavaScript validate schema against list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, recursion

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Given a list of employees like with various properties.

```
const employees = [
 { name: 'alice',
   title: "ceo",
   salary: 100,
   reports: [{
      name: "bob",
      title: "cfo",
      salary: 10,
      reports: [{
        name: 'zorp',
        title:"controller",
        salary: 40
      }],
   }],
},
…
]
```

Note the “reports” property in particular. An employee can have properties that are also lists of employees.

And a schema object

```
const schema = {
  employee: [
    {
    name: "name",
    required: true,
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    name: "title",
    required: true,
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    name: "salary",
    required: false,
    type: "number"
  },
  {
    name: "remote",
    required: false,
    type: "boolean"
  },
  {
    name: "reports",
    required: false,
    type: "array:employee"
  },
]
}
```

complete the validate function (we just need to return the first case that fails)

```
function validate(employees,schema) {

/*
- There are multiple test cases, if the test cases all pass you should return
‍‌‌‌‍‍‌‍‌‍‍‌‍‍‌‌‍‌‌‍
     { ok: true, message: "success" }

- if a required property doesn't exist on the validation, you should return 

     { ok: false, message: "${name} does not exist" }

- if a property type is invalid, you should return

     { ok: false, message: "${name} property invalid ${type}" }

- if a property does not belong as part of the schema, you should return

     { ok: false, message: "property ${name} does not belong" }

*/

}
```

Comment: so what you've tried so far?

Comment: you search something like this https://joi.dev/ ?

Comment: @ericmp i have tried a solution but with failed test cases, pasting it here might cause confusion

Comment: so when u go to the mechanic u go without the car? or u bring it to actually let the mechanic see what is going on? same here

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are experiencing is that your data is recursive and your schema is linear, ie "flat". You attempted to encode meaning into strings like "boolean" and "array:employee". This is a poor way of trying to represent your recursive structure as a schema.

If you want to build a proper schema validator, start by designing pieces for making the schemas. Use basics and work your way up -

**design**

```js
// main.js

import { primitives, validate } from "./schema.js"

const [tnumber, tboolean, tstring] = primitives()

const temployee = ...

const tschema = ...

const mydata = ...

validate(tschema, mydata)
```

With our primitives defined, we can make more advanced types, like `temployee` and `tschema` -

```js
// main.js

import { primitives, validate, required, optional } from "./schema.js"

const [tnumber, tboolean, tstring] = primitives()

const temployee = {
  name: required(tstring),
  title: required(tstring),
  salary: optional(tnumber),
  remote: optional(tboolean),
  get reports() { return optional(tschema) } // recursive types supported!
}

const tschema = [temployee] // array of temployee!

const mydata = ...

validate(tschema, mydata)
```

**implement**

Now we start the Schema module -

- `primitives` - generates symbolic primitive types
- `required` - type guards against null values
- `optional` - type validates only if value is present

```js
// schema.js

function *primitives() { while(true) yield Symbol() }

const required = t => v => {
  if (v == null)
    throw Error(`cannot be null`)
  validate(t, v)
}

const optional = t => v => {
  if (v != null)
    validate(t, v)
}

export { primitives, required, optional }
```

Next we'll write an internal helper, `validatePrimitive`, for validating basic types -

```js
// schema.js (continued)

function validatePrimitive(t, v) {
  switch(t) {
    case tnumber:
      if (v?.constructor != Number)
        throw Error(`${v} is not a number`)
      break
    case tboolean:
      if (v?.constructor != Boolean)
        throw Error(`${v} is not a boolean`)
      break
    case tstring:
      if (v?.constructor != String)
        throw Error(`${v} is not a string`)
      break
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported primitive type`)
  }
}
```

Finally we write the public `validate` interface. It's recursive because both the schemas and the data we are validating are recursive. This harmony of data and code makes it easier for us to think about the problem and write a program that solves it -

```js
// schema.js (continued)

function validate(t, v) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Symbol:
      return validatePrimitive(t, v)
    case Array:
      if (t.length !== 1) throw Error("Array schema must specify exactly one type")
      for (const k of Object.keys(v))
        validate(t[0], v[k])
      break
    case Object:
      for (const k of Object.keys(t))
        validate(t[k], v[k])
      break
    case Function:
      t(v)
      break
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported schema: ${t}`)
  }
}

export { ..., validate }
```

**run it**

```js
import { primitives, required, optional, validate } from "./schema.js"

const [tnumber, tboolean, tstring] = primitives()

const temployee = {
  name: required(tstring),
  title: required(tstring),
  salary: optional(tnumber),
  remote: optional(tboolean),
  get reports() { return optional(tschema) }
}

const tschema = [temployee] // array of temployee

const employees = [
  { name: 'alice',
    title: "ceo",
    salary: 100,
    reports: [{
      name: "bob",
      title: "cfo",
      salary: 10,
      reports: [{
        name: 'zorp',
        title:"controller",
        salary: 40
      }],
    }],
  },
  …
]

validate(tschema, employees) // throws an Error only if invalid
```

**what's next?**

You could design more schema tools like -

- `withDefault(t, defaultValue)` - substitutes null values with a default

  ```js
  const temployee = {
    name: tstring,
    remote: withDefault(tboolean, false)
  }

  const tstudent = {
    name: tstring,
    major: withDefault(tstring, "undeclared")
  }

  const tcourse = {
    teacher: temployee,
    enrollments: withDefault([tstudent], [])
  }
  ```
- `inRange(min, max)` - numeric range guards

  ```js
  const temployee = {
    name: tstring,
    salary: inRange(0, Infinity) // negative salary invalid! 
  }
  ```
- `oneOf(t, choices)` - inclusive value guards

  ```js
  const temployee = {
    name: tstring,
    title: oneOf(tstring, ["exec", "vp", "staff"]) // must be one of these!
  }
  ```

We could improve the error messages by adding `try..catch` around the recursive calls. This allows us to add context to the point of failure so the user knows the full path to the offending leaf -

```js
// schema.js (continued)

function validate(t, v) {
  let k
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Symbol:
      return validatePrimitive(t, v)
    case Array:
      if (t.length !== 1) throw Error("Array schema must specify exactly one type")
      try {
        for (k of Object.keys(v))
          validate(t[0], v[k])
      }
      catch (err) {
        throw Error(`${k}th child invalid: ${err.message}`)
      }
      break
    case Object:
      try {
        for (k of Object.keys(t))
          validate(t[k], v[k])
      }
      catch (err) {
        throw Error(`${k} invalid: ${err.message}`)
      }
      break
    case Function:
      t(v)
      break
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported schema: ${t}`)
  }
}
```

Maybe export common types like -

- `temail` - a valid email address
- `tphone` - numeric string with accepted punctuation
- `tpassword` - string at least 20 characters

Choose "required" or "optional" as the default behavior. Currently these have the same effect -

```js
const temployee = {
  name: required(tstring),
  ...
}

const temployee = {
  name: tstring,  // null is not a string, so null will fail validation
  ...
}
```

This means `required` is implicit and we can remove it from our Schema module. Users are expected to use `optional` or `withDefault` when nullary values are acceptable.

**remarks**

Remember all complex things are made from combining simple things.  If you design things that cannot be combined, you are writing dead-end code.

This means we can write sophisticated validation expresssions by combining other validation expressions! Consider adding validation combinators like `and` and `or`, among others.

```js
const tuser = {
  newPassword:
    // password must be
    //   at least 20 characters
    //   AND at most 40 characters
    //   AND include 2 symbols
    and(minLength(20), maxLength(40), requireSymbols(2))
  ...
}
```

```js
const tuser = {
  newPassword:
    // password can be
    //   at least 20 characters
    //   OR 8 characters AND includes 2 symbols
    or(minLength(20), and(requireSymbols(2), minLength(8)))
  ...
}
```